# Cake3 Paginator Sort Error

Tags: sorting, cakephp-3.0, paginator

I have a very simply model which I want to paginate. The pagination works but the sort links do not have any effect:

My Controller:

```
public $paginate = [
        'limit' => 10,
        'order' => [
            'Properties.id' => 'asc'
        ],
        'sortWhitelist' => [
            'Properties.id',
            'Properties.name',
            'Properties.active'
        ],
];
```

My query:

```
$properties = $this->Properties->find('all')->where($options)->contain($contains)->order(['Properties.id']);

$this->set('properties', $this->paginate($properties));
```

My view displays 10 items per page and the links to pages/next/previous work fine. When I click the sort link:

```
$this->Paginator->sort('id', 'ID')
```

The url called is:

**properties/index/3?sort=id&direction=desc**

The page re-loads but the order of the data does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whitelist expects the exact field name that you are using in sort. It will not automatically prepend the primary table's name, so your whitelist should look like this:

```
public $paginate = [
    'limit' => 10,
    'order' => [
        'Properties.id' => 'asc'
    ],
    'sortWhitelist' => [
        'id',
        'name',
        'active'
    ],
];
```

It will see "id" in the query and check that the exact field name "id" exists in the whitelist.

Also, it appears you are including an `order()` on your query. To allow the paginator to set the order, you should remove this clause.

Comment: Yes it was the order/sort that I had added to the main query! Good lesson learned today!